# Using an array and a loop and the push function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

what I'm trying to do is to get 4 movieclipps (leaf1, leaf2, leaf3, leaf4) to play the sound that is attached to them when is dragged onto another movieclip (NatureTarget) and the play button is pressed so that the sounds are played in the order they are dragged on. I know I need to use an array and the push function and a loop...but I am lost. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code so that we can see how far along you are?

Answer (score 0):

I made a crude example, hopefully giving you an idea of how to go about solving your problem. It would have helped if you posted some of your code as I could have tailored this answer to it. Anyway just copy and paste the code into you document root to see it work.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _leafVector:Vector.<Leaf>;
        private var _nature:Nature;
        private var _playButton:PlayButton;
        private var _leafPlayList:LeafPlayList;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            var soundsXml:XML = 

            <sounds>
                <sound name="sound1" url="sounds/sound1.mp3" />
                <sound name="sound2" url="sounds/sound2.mp3" />
                <sound name="sound3" url="sounds/sound3.mp3" />
                <sound name="sound4" url="sounds/sound4.mp3" />
            </sounds>

            _leafVector = new Vector.<Leaf>();

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < soundsXml.children().length(); i++)
            {
                var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest(soundsXml.sound[i].@url));

                var leaf:Leaf = new Leaf(String(i+1), sound, soundsXml.sound[i].@name);
                leaf.x = i * leaf.width;
                addChild(leaf);

                leaf.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onLeafMouseDown);
                leaf.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onLeafMouseUp);

                _leafVector.push(leaf);

            }// end for

            _nature = new Nature();
            _nature.x = _leafVector[3].x + _leafVector[3].width;
            addChildAt(_nature, 0);

            _playButton = new PlayButton();
            _playButton.x = _nature.x;
            _playButton.y = _nature.height; 
            addChild(_playButton);

            _playButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlayButtonClick);

            _leafPlayList = new LeafPlayList();
            _leafPlayList.x = _playButton.x;
            _leafPlayList.y = _playButton.y + _playButton.height; 
            addChild(_leafPlayList);

        }// end function

        private function onLeafMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var leaf:Leaf = Leaf(e.currentTarget);
            leaf.stopDrag();

            if (leaf.dropTarget == _nature)
            {
                _leafPlayList.addLeafSound(leaf.soundName, leaf.sound);
                leaf.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onLeafMouseDown);
                leaf.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onLeafMouseUp);

            }// end function

        }// end function

        private function onLeafMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var leaf:Leaf = Leaf(e.currentTarget);
            this.setChildIndex(leaf, this.numChildren-1);
            leaf.startDrag();

        }// end function

        private function onPlayButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            _leafPlayList.playLeafSounds();

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.text.TextField;

internal class Leaf extends Sprite
{
    private var _sound:Sound;
    private var _soundName:String;

    public function get soundName():String
    {
        return _soundName;
    }// end function

    public function get sound():Sound
    {
        return _sound;

    }// end function

    public function Leaf(text:String, sound:Sound, soundName:String)
    {
        _sound = sound;
        _soundName = soundName;
        graphics.lineStyle(1);
        graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
        graphics.drawCircle(25, 25, 25);
        graphics.endFill();

        var textField:TextField = new TextField();
        textField.text = text;
        textField.x = width / 2;
        textField.y = height / 2;
        textField.selectable = false;
        addChild(textField);

    }// end function

}// end class

internal class Nature extends Sprite
{
    public function Nature()
    {
        graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF00);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        graphics.endFill();

    }// end function

}// end class

internal class PlayButton extends Sprite
{
    public function PlayButton()
    {
        graphics.lineStyle(1);
        graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100,25);
        graphics.endFill();

        var textField:TextField = new TextField();
        textField.text = "PLAY BUTTON";
        textField.selectable = false;
        addChild(textField);

    }// end function

}// end class

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

internal class LeafPlayList extends Sprite
{
    private var _soundChannel:SoundChannel;
    private var _leafSoundVector:Vector.<Sound>;
    private var _position:int;
    private var _playListTextField:TextField;

    public function LeafPlayList()
    {
        _playListTextField = new TextField();
        addChild(_playListTextField);
        _soundChannel = new SoundChannel();
        _leafSoundVector = new Vector.<Sound>();

    }// end function

    public function addLeafSound(soundName:String, sound:Sound):void
    {
        _playListTextField.appendText("\n" + soundName);
        _leafSoundVector.push(sound);

    }// end function

    public function playLeafSounds():void
    {
        _soundChannel.stop();
        _position = 1;
        _soundChannel = _leafSoundVector[_position - 1].play();
        _soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundChannelSoundComplete);

    }// end function

    private function onSoundChannelSoundComplete(e:Event):void
    {
        if (!(_position == _leafSoundVector.length)) _position++
        else _position = 1;

        playNexLeafSound();

    }// end function

    private function playNexLeafSound():void
    {
        _soundChannel = _leafSoundVector[_position - 1].play();
        _soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundChannelSoundComplete);

    }// end function

}// end class
```